# Filter pdf text by font wih pdfminer

Tags: python, pdfminer, pdfminersix

So I am using pdfminer.six to extract text by a specific font. But currently I have this following problem:

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextContainer, LTChar

def extract_text_by_font(pdf_file):
    extracted_text = ""

    for page_layout in extract_pages(pdf_file):
        for element in page_layout:
            if isinstance(element, LTTextContainer):
                for text_line in element:
                    for character in text_line:
                        if isinstance(character, LTChar):
                            extracted_text += character.get_text()

    return extracted_text
```

If I compare output from this function with from `pdfminer.high_level.extract_text`, then `extract_text_by_font` does not extract the text properly. For example with `pdfminer.high_level.extract_text` I get

"... Hello World..."

but with `extract_text_by_font` I get

"...HelloWorld...".

So it removes sometime the whitespaces. Can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from pdfminer.high_level import extract_pages
from pdfminer.layout import LTTextContainer, LTChar

def extract_text_by_font(pdf_file):
    extracted_text = ""
    prev_x = 0

    for page_layout in extract_pages(pdf_file):
        for element in page_layout:
            if isinstance(element, LTTextContainer):
                for text_line in element:
                    for character in text_line:
                        if isinstance(character, LTChar):
                            # Adding a space if the difference in x-coordinates
                            # is more than the character width.
                            if character.x0 - prev_x > character.width:
                                extracted_text += ' '

                            extracted_text += character.get_text()
                            prev_x = character.x0 + character.width

    return extracted_text
```

Comment: Thank you, but it does not completely solve the problem.

Comment: But I can add a constant c to `character.x0  -  prev_x > c * character.width`.